# How to update record using mysql join?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my mysql I am having t1, t2 tables and I want to update t1's field from t2's field value based on t1's field value match t2's field value

I tried the below but it is not updating. What I did wrongly here

```
UPDATE t1 
INNER JOIN t2 
ON t1.name = t2.name 
SET t1.age = t2.age 
WHERE t1.name IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate the table you want to update from the table your querying, even though it is the same:

```
UPDATE t1  
SET t1.age = t2.age
FROM t1 as tempT1
INNER JOIN t2 
ON tempT1.name = t2.name 
WHERE tempT1.name IS NOT NULL;
```

**UPDATE**
Apparently MySQL is using a different `UPDATE JOIN` Syntax than other db's. Your initial query seems to use the correct syntax, just to be sure try to alias the table names:

```
UPDATE t1 temp1
INNER JOIN t2 temp2
ON temp1.name = temp2.name 
SET temp1.age = temp2.age 
WHERE temp1.name IS NOT NULL;
```

**UPDATE 2**
After looking at this a bit longer I'm certain that the `WHERE` clause is the issue:
`WHERE temp1.name IS NOT NULL`
You cannot join on null values anyway, so they are filtered out by default. The `WHERE` clause is somehow interfering with the join.
Try and remove it to see if the `UPDATE`works. If you don' t want to execute and update right away simply execute a select with the same `JOIN CLAUSE` to see which records would be affected.

Here is a general reference to `NULL` and `JOIN`:
http://databases.about.com/library/weekly/aa051203a.htm

Here is the SQL Server Reference in compliance with the above:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190409.aspx

Could not find a MySQL reference that states this explicitly but I think this is true for all Relational DBs.

Comment: I am getting this "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM t1 as tempT1 INNER JOIN t2 ON tempT1.name = t2' at line 1..

Comment: My mysql version is "mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.49, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.1"

Comment: just checked, the MySQL syntax for update joins seems to be different than for other db's checked you sample but can't find something wrong either, seems to follow the MySQL syntax

Comment: checked again and by now I'm certain that the issue is the where clause, the null values are filtered out anyway and the where clause is somehow interfering with the join

Answer (score 1):

I myself also found another way to achieve this same scenario. I am pasting the answer here so that others will get benefit.

```
UPDATE t1 SET t2_age = (SELECT age FROM t2 BINARY WHERE name = t1.name);
```

Comment: Recently I found another drawback form above code. It is not case sensitive. So some time it found two records like this "Jak", "jak". So I updated the query by adding BINARY for case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update t1
set t1.age = t2.age
from t1
inner join t2 on t1.name = t2.name
where t1.name is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE t1,t2  
SET t1.age = t2.age
FROM t1 as tempT1
INNER JOIN t2 ON tempT1.name = t2.name 
WHERE tempT1.name IS NOT NULL;
```