# In MySQL, how to update some columns of existing rows and insert new rows from a reference table?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, left-join

The following will get me values from a reference table `t2` I want to insert to or to update existing tuple with in table `t1`:

```
SELECT 
  id, col1 
FROM 
  t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  t1
ON 
  t2.id=t1.id
```

If a tuple with `id` already exist in `t1`, it should be updated with the value selected from `t2`.  If a tuple with `id` does not exist in `t1`, `(id, col1)` should be inserted with other columns set to default values.

How to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

use this two `querys:`

This will join and filter, giving you the values that exists in both tables, so you just do the update

```
    Update t1 set t1.col1 = t2.col1
from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

This will join and filter, giving you the values that are in t2, but not in t1, so you just do the insert.

```
    insert into t1 select t2.id, t2.col1 
from t2 left outer join t1 on t2.id = t1.id where t1.id IS NULL
```

**UPDATE:**

as I can see from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532456/how-to-update-record-using-mysql-join) MySQL uses another sintax for this. So you query may work with this instead of the query above:

```
UPDATE t1 temp1
INNER JOIN t2 temp2
ON temp1.id= temp2.id 
SET temp1.col1= temp2.col1
```

but the concepts are the same (just a different syntax)
You won't need the Where, because the INNER JOIN will only use fields that match/join.

Comment: Is `t1.id = t2.id, ` in the first query necessary?

Comment: in the update ? No, just put the fields you want to update. In the join ? Yes, it's neccesary

Comment: In the first query, don't you need `Update t1 SET t1.col1 = t2.col1
WHERE t1.id = t2.id FROM t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id WHERE t2.id IS NOT NULL`?

Comment: I said "in the _first_ query".

Comment: you don't need the Where clause, because in the join you got the data related, so SQL will update every field with the value related from the other table. Check the edit, I remove the Set t1.id = t2.id, as you put in your comment